# Django daterangefield in a form

Tags: django, date-range

I have a model looking like this:

**models.py**

```
class CommissionElection(models.Model):
    electable_time = DateRangeField()
```

And my form looks like this:

**forms.py**

```
class CreateCommissionElection(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
            model = CommissionElection
            fields = ['electable_time',]
```

Right now the electable time displays like this:
[image]

What widget is needed to make the fields datefields instead of charfields, so you can pick a date out of a calendar instead of writing it out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify a different widget for a `date` field:

```
from django.forms.widgets import DateInput


class MyDateInput(DateInput):
    input_type = 'date'
```

next we can make a form `DateField` field for this:

```
from django.forms.fields import DateField


class MyDateField(DateField):
    widget = MyDateInput
```

and reuse that in a `DateRangeField`:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.forms.ranges import DateRangeField


class MyDateRangeField(DateRangeField):
    base_field = MyDateField
```

then we can use this as field:

```
class CreateCommissionElection(forms.ModelForm):
    electable_time = MyDateRangeField()

    class Meta:
        model = CommissionElection
        fields = [
            'electable_time',
        ]
```

Comment: To get `MyDateInput` to work properly for editing, you may need to add:

`    def format_value(self, value: datetime) -> str:
        if not value:
            return ""
        return value.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")`

Otherwise the value in the field will be set using a default date formatting function which probably isn't what the web browser will expect.